# Lucene check if certain docIds is in a OpenBitSetDISI

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Given an instance of OpenBitSetDISI. How can I check if a single document, or a list of document ids,  are present in the list. Or is iterating through the OpenBitSetDISI the only option?

```
OpenBitSetDISI set = new OpenBitSetDISI(filter.GetDocIdSet(reader).Iterator(), reader.MaxDoc);
```

Using Lucene.NET 3.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's effectively a bit array with a bit set for each docId included.

So Get(docId) should return true is the id is in the set, false if not.